# npm modules как правильно пользоваться?

Tags: javascript, npm

Мои познания о npm ограничиваются тем, что мы создаем файл package.json, в нем пишем зависимости, запускаем npm install и типа все качается.

Сейчас я копирую нужные мне файлы в public папку моего проекта, что, как мне кажется, явно не то, как должно быть. Отсюда вопрос, как правильно пользоваться скачанными модулями, не перетаскивая нужные файлы вручную?

Comment: про сборщики почитайте

Comment: дополню предыдущий комментарий: Grunt, Gulp, Webpack, Parcel